# How can I develop an alarm option in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nsthread, alarm

I have two questions:

1. How can I develop an Alarm option in iPhone application ?
2. We should able to activate more than an Alarm in the app. We can use NSTimer, NSThread and etc... So which will give good performance ?

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in the foreground, use NSTimer to either provide timer ticks or the final timeout value.   When the app is sent to the background you'll need to set up a UILocalNotification, to be sent with the remaining time left on the alarm.

Comment: Already I have setup the local notification and alarm everything... now the problem is; if i set more than an alarm, app is getting very slow... (I am using NSTimer...). And also background process is not working at all (timer).

Answer (score 0):

Running an NSTimer that does every second

```
NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date];
if ([dateNow compare:alarm.date] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Should work.